# How can I position the JLabel and JButton in the center of the gui window in java

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I am practicing GUI in java. I am currently struggling with the placement of the elements. I want the JLabel to be in the center middle of the gui window and the button to be right below the JLabel. I wanna preface that I am a beginner in Java so I may have some lapses so I would appreciate some help/ tips as well!

I tried different layout manager(BoxLayout, GridLayout, BorderLayout, and FlowLayout) but neither of them worked. So far, FlowLayout was the closest but whenever I run the code the JLabel is placed on top and is seemingly cut off while the button is at the very bottom of the gui window.

here's a preview of my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public MyFrame(){
        //panel for label
        JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        //label for the intro
        JLabel introLabel = new JLabel();
        introLabel.setText("Welcome User");
        introLabel.setForeground(new Color(129, 245, 71));
        introLabel.setFont(new Font("Digital-7", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        introLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        labelPanel.add(introLabel);

        // panel for button
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        //JButton
        JButton button = new JButton("click");
        button.setFocusable(false);
        buttonPanel.add(button);

        //main content panel
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //set content of the pane
        this.setContentPane(mainPanel);

        //frame constructor
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("encrypt your message");
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0x151414)); // the gui bg is determined by the pane
        this.setResizable(false);

        //layout manager
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) There is no need for the "mainPanel". The content pane of the frame is a JPanel with a Border layout. 2) Don't create a separate panel for each component. I would use a panel with a GridBagLayout. Add the label and button to the panel on two separate rows. Then just add this panel to the CENTER of the content pane. By default the components will be centered horizontally and vertically. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to do something like this. `BoxLayout` is your friend if you want things to be stacked. Also, you can use a `GridBagLayout` in a 'shorthand` way to get things centred in a container:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public MyFrame() {
        // panel for label
        JPanel basePanell = new JPanel();
        basePanell.setLayout(new BoxLayout(basePanell, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        // label for the intro
        JLabel introLabel = new JLabel();
        introLabel.setText("Welcome User");
        introLabel.setForeground(new Color(129, 245, 71));
        introLabel.setFont(new Font("Digital-7", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        introLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        basePanell.add(introLabel);

        // JButton
        JButton button = new JButton("click");
        button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        basePanell.add(button);

        // Improve appearance
        basePanell.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        // Stunt to centre the base panel
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        getContentPane().add(basePanell);

        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("encrypt your message");
        // getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0x151414)); // the gui bg is
        // determined by the pane
        getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0xAAAAAA)); // the gui bg is determined by the pane
        setResizable(false);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            EventQueue.invokeAndWait(() -> {
                MyFrame f = new MyFrame();
                f.setSize(500, 500);
                f.setVisible(true);
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```